# add route in Linux if sub-net, where gateway is situated, is not configured

Tags: ip, routing, iproute

I have a PC which has 192.168.1.1/24 configured to eth0 interface. Now if I try to add routes via 10.10.10.254, the `ip` utility reports that `No such process`:

```
root@PC:~# ip neigh add 10.10.10.254 lladdr 00:01:02:03:04:05 dev eth0
root@PC:~# ip route add default via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
root@PC:~# ip route add 172.16.0.1/32 via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
root@PC:~#
```

As long as PC knows the MAC address of 10.10.10.254 it is technically possible to send data via 10.10.10.254 while 10/8 network is not configured to any interface in PC. Based on my example it would use PCs eth0 MAC address as a source MAC, 00:01:02:03:04:05 as a destination MAC, 192.168.1.1 as a source IP address and destination address would be whatever I specify.

Is it possible to force Linux to add a route if sub-net, where gateway is situated, is not in configured to an interface?

Comment: before we (try to) answer, which combination of `route add foo/X ...`  have you tried ?

Comment: I have tried `ip route add default via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0` and `ip route add 172.16.0.1/32 via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0`. However, the point does not seem to be which destination network I use, but the fact that eth0 interface does not have address from the same broadcast domain that 10.10.10.254.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
ip route add 172.16.0.1/32 via 10.10.10.254 dev eth0 onlink
```